# An inequality for an increasing, concave function

Tags: analysis, functions, inequality, convex-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ be a smooth function such that $f(0)=0$,
$f''<0$,  $f'(x)>0$ for $x\in(0,N)$ and $f'(N)=0$. I would like to show that
$$
\max_{x\in(0,\infty)}\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{1+|f(k)-x|}\bigg)=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{1+f(N)-f(k)},
$$
i.e. the maximum is attained at $x=f(N)$.

The geometric considerations seem to confirm the validity of the above claim, but I don't know how to formalize the proof. Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: Some details might need to be checked: since $f''(x)<0$, if $f'(x)$ is ever negative then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = -\infty$, which means it can't map to the codomain $(0,\infty)$. Or do you mean that $f''(x)<0$ is mandated only for $x<N$?

Comment: You're right, the problem didn't make sense the way it was written. Thanks for pointing it out. I corrected it and I believe it should be okay now.

Comment: Can't stop to think about this--and maybe I would have nothing to contribute--but when I saw your title my first thought was: Jensen's inequality.  Maybe that would be useful.

Comment: Perhaps, but I can't quite see how to use it here yet...

Comment: It's still not clear to me what (if anything) is being assumed about $f$ and its derivatives when $x>N$.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but $f'(N) = 0$ together with the concavity and non-negativeness implies that $f$ is constant on $[N, \infty)$.

Comment: In the question, only the function values $f(1), \ldots, f(N)$ appear. Hence, the behaviour of $f$ on $(N,\infty)$ does not matter at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $N = 3$, $f(x) = x \, (2 N - x)$ yields a counterexample. Denote
$$
g(y) := \sum_{k = 1}^N \frac{1}{1 + |f(k) - y|}.$$

Then,
$$
1.1181 \approx g(f(2)) > g(f(3)) \approx 1.0928.$$

(Actually, one has to modify $f$ slightly to obtain a smooth function $f \colon [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$, but this can be done without changing $f(1), f(2)$ and $f(3)$)